Is there a pattern for the wake of a ship with a changing velocity and a constant acceleration?
My question may sound silly. I do not have a physics background. I have already learnt about Kelvin wake pattern, which assumes a constant velocity. And I have understood that under such circumstance, the wake is a V shape.

But if a ship's velocity is reducing with a constant acceleration but still quicker than the disturbance, will there be a pattern of the ship wake, maybe associated with the initial velocity and the acceleration? I tried to find an answer in Linear and Nonlinear Waves, of Whitham, but I failed.


Even for zero deceleration there are complications….
